# Custom controller pagination using standard set

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I'm stuck on standard set controller pagination for my case study as it requires if statements to create a list query which i can't convert to string

here's the codes so far

```
<apex:page controller="Ctrl_ContactSearch" sidebar="false">
<apex:form id="err">
    <apex:messages id="err"/>
</apex:form>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Criteria" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="acco" columns="4">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="4" width="200%">
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:outputText value="{!Acct.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Country" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="Contact Name" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="Account Type" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!Name}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!country}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!contacts}" />
                <apex:selectList id="countries" value="{!picklist}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Type}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
                <div align="right">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchAccount}" reRender="account-table,err" onclick="showLoadingDialog();" oncomplete="hideLoadingDialog();" />
                </div>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results"  id="account-table" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!isRenderedNoResult}">
            <i>{!NoResultsFound}</i>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="c" rendered="{!isRendered}">
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}">
                    {!c.Account.Name}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Billing Country</apex:facet>
                    {!c.Account.BillingCountry}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Shipping Country</apex:facet>
                    {!c.Account.ShippingCountry}
                </apex:column>    
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Contact Name</apex:facet>
                    {!c.Name}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Types</apex:facet>
                    {!c.Account.Type}
                </apex:column>                                                       
                <apex:column headerValue="Year Created">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!c.Account.CreatedDate}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
             <apex:panelGrid columns="4">                
            <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="searchBlock" value="<<" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
            <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="searchBlock" value="<" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
            <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="searchBlock" value=">" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
            <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="searchBlock" value=">>" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>                 
            <apex:outputPanel >                      
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:panelGrid> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<script>
var label = document.getElementById("accountLabel");
</script>    
</apex:page>
```

and the controller class

```
public class Ctrl_ContactSearch {
public Account acct { get; set; }
public List<Contact> acc { get; set; }
public String name { get; set; }
public String country { get; set; }
public String contacts { get; set; }
public string pick{set;get;}
public string picklist{set;get;}   
public string NoResultsFound {set; get;}
public boolean isRendered {set; get;}
public boolean isRenderedNoResult {set; get;}   

transient List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = new List<Schema.PicklistEntry>();
public List<SelectOption> getType(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Type.getDescribe();
    ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    options.add(new SelectOption('--', '--'));
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }    
    return options; 
}       
public Ctrl_ContactSearch(){
    acc = new List<Contact>();
    acct = new Account();
    isRenderedNoResult = true;    
    NoResultsFound = 'No matching records.';
}    
public PageReference searchAccount(){ 
    isRendered = true;
    isRenderedNoResult = false;
    name = name.replace('*','%');  
    if(country.length()!=0){
        country='%'+country+'%';
    }
    if(name.length()>=2){           
        if(country.length()!=0){
            if(contacts.length()!=0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) and account.Type= :picklist and Name = :contacts order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) and Name = :contacts order by account.name asc];
                }
            }
            if (contacts.length()==0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) and account.Type= :picklist order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) order by account.name asc];
                }
            }
        }
        if(country.length()==0){
            if(contacts.length()!=0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and Name = :contacts and account.Type= :picklist order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and Name = :contacts order by account.name asc];
                }
            }
            if(contacts.length()==0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name and account.Type= :picklist order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Name LIKE :name order by account.name asc];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(name.length()==0){
        if(country.length()!=0){
            if(contacts.length()!=0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) and account.Type= :picklist and Name = :contacts order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where(account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) and Name = :contacts order by account.name asc];
                }
            }
            if (contacts.length()==0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) and account.Type= :picklist order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){ 
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where (account.BillingCountry LIKE :country or account.ShippingCountry LIKE :country) order by account.name asc];
                } 
            }
        }
        if(country.length()==0){
            if(contacts.length()!=0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){ 
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where Name = :contacts and account.Type= :picklist order by account.name asc];
                } 
                if(picklist.length()==2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where Name = :contacts order by account.name asc ];
                }
            }
            if(contacts.length()==0){
                if(picklist.length()!=2){
                    acc = [select account.id, account.name, account.type, account.billingcountry, account.shippingcountry, name, account.createddate from contact
                           where account.Type= :picklist 
                           order by account.name asc];
                }
                if(picklist.length()==2){                       
                    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please provide a value for at least 1 of the available criteria.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    isRendered = false;
                    isRenderedNoResult = true; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(name.length()==1){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'A minimum of 2 characters is required to search using the Account Name.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        isRendered = false;
        isRenderedNoResult = true; 

    }
    if(acc.size()==0){
        isRendered = false;
        isRenderedNoResult = true; 
    }        
    return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm#!). However, you do not need Dynamic SOQL to use a [standard set controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm). SFSE can provide you with more assistance if you can make your question [specific and detailed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); it's not totally clear what you need here.

Comment: Please do not blank out your questions once you've received an answer. By doing so you eliminate the usefulness of the question and answer to the community.

Answer (score 2):

[`ApexPages.StandardSetController`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) does not require the use of Dynamic SOQL. Here's an example from the documentation for that class (linked above):

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = 
new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name,CloseDate FROM Opportunity]));
```

You can pass your static SOQL query directly to `Database.getQueryLocator()` when you initialize the `StandardSetController`.

Your use case does seem appealing for the use of [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm#!). Dynamic SOQL allows you to construct your queries in the form of a string, including by using templating with `String.format()`. It's a powerful (but sometimes very tricky) tool, and it's important to note that values you use in Dynamic SOQL need to be escaped to prevent SOQL injection attacks by using `String.escapeSingleQuotes()` or by using simple Apex binds, as you currently do.

Before going down that road, I'd work on your logical structure. Rather than using enormously complex chains of `if` and `else` statements on the lengths of various variables (the details of which I have not spent the time to parse out), I would recommend you establish Boolean variables and try as best you can to flatten your logic.

It might look something like this:

```
Boolean hasCountry = String.isNotBlank(country);
Boolean hasContacts = String.isNotBlank(contacts);
Boolean hasPicklist = String.isNotBlank(picklist);
// or whatever criteria you need to establish semantics of the user input.
```

Then think through a truth table: how many different combinations of these true/false situations are there? Do any of them reduce to the same behavior?

If you stick with static SOQL, write your logic out using *semantic* statements about what information you have, rather than what your variables look like:

```
if (hasCountry && hasContacts && hasPicklist) {
     // do one kind of query.
}
if (hasCountry && hasContacts && !hasPicklist) {
    // do another
}
if (hasCountry && !hasContacts && hasPicklist) {
    // yet a third
}
```

If you switch to Dynamic SOQL, you may be able to dramatically reduce the code's length by simply starting from a core query and appending clauses based on the values:

```
String query = 'SELECT STUFF_GOES_HERE FROM Contact WHERE ';
List<String> whereClauses = new List<String>();

if (hasCountry) {
     whereClause.add('Account.BillingCountry LIKE :country');
}

// And so on...

query += String.join(whereClauses, ' AND ');
```

Then, finally, perform a dynamic query.

(Please note that these examples aren't meant to be specific to your use case, but illustrative of some approaches to constructing the logic. I see several situations where your logic at a quick read appears to be duplicative or non-exhaustive. This represents either a bug or simply code whose branching complexity is too high to be easily understood).